# ¿Como muestro una lista de items en un Datalist? (en ASP)

Tags: c#, asp.net, lista, aplicación-web, asp

Tengo una lista con la información de un producto específico, que selecciono  gracias a una clase Producto y a un Stored Procedure en mi BD

```
List<Producto> producto = new List<Producto>();
```

que recoge los siguientes datos

```
public class Producto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_tienda { get; set; }
    public string Nombre_prod { get; set; }
    public string Descrip_prod { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio_Unit { get; set; }
    public string Img_origen { get; set; }
    public string fullinfo
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Nombre_prod} {Descrip_prod} {Precio_Unit}";
        }
    }
}
```

el string "fullinfo" lo uso para concatenar todo y mostrarlo en una ListBox. Supongo que para un datalist, tendría que mostrar cada item por separado, pero no logro encontrar info sobre como hacerlo.

```
public void UpdateBinding()
    {
        listaencontrados.DataSource = producto;
        listaencontrados.DataTextField = "fullinfo";
        listaencontrados.DataBind();
    }
```

por ahora, lo que puedo hacer es mostrar todos y cada uno de los productos en mi base de datos dentro de un DataList, pero no uno o varios productos específicos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]